# Displaying Korean Characters - iOS App

Tags: objective-c, ios, unicode, internationalization, cjk

I am trying to display Korean text in my iPhone app. The app appends the Unicode of letters one by one to an NSMutableString and displays the string on the screen after each letter is appended.

I understand that there are some rules for conjoining letters (Jamo).

Is there a function for automatically applying all these rules to a string of letters or do I need to write code to make changes (e.g., changing a consonant to a tail consonant if there is a vowel before it)?

Comment: Why is it appending them one by one?  And why are they coming incorrectly?

Comment: As the user writes the letters, the app recognizes them one by one  and displays them on the screen. For each Korean letter (Jamo) there are several unicodes and they have different properties (they may conjoin with previous letters, etc). If the wrong unicode is used, then the letter may not conjoin. Also, if the wrong unicode is used, the user will not be able to put the cursor before the letter!

Comment: Are you not using the iOS system korean keyboard?

Comment: No, I am not using the keyboard. The user writes the characters on the screen and the app recognizes them. I have written code to apply some of the rules and convert the unicodes, but there are some problems with conversion and as a result for example, the cursor doesn't move around correctly, etc. So I thought maybe there is a better way of doing the conversion by using a function to apply all the rules, but so far I haven't been able to find any function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FCA. It's you who sent email to me, right? Because the more detailed question is here, I will try (my best) to answer here instead of replying to your email.

By reading the whole text you and people wrote here, I figured out that you are making a Korean handwriting recognition software. So, you would not enjoy the luxury of the Korean input method provided by Apple.

There are two things for me to say. Let's go one by one. (I believe you are already aware of one of the two things I'm going to explain.)

1. How to compose Hangul text.

   So, by reading your inquiry, it should not be about Unicode composed/decomposed Korean string (or just a series of Ja (Consonants) and Mo (Vowels)). Your question looks to be about "how to determine if a consonant (your term is tail consonant, right?) a user writes is a last consonant or the begining consonant of next syllable.
   Best thing is to learn Korean, but let me briefly explain it.

Let's say you write 소방차 (a Fire dept. car.)
You are to write : ㅅㅗㅂㅏㅇㅊㅏ
(Again I'm not talking about the decomposed form of Unicode. It's about how people write Korean text.)

When you type ㅗ (which is the 2nd char) temporarily a display system displays 소 by attaching the ㅗ to its preceding ㅅ. And it will look up Korean table. (Although how to assemble Hangul is JoHap style (조합형), which is called composite style, there are tables of allowed Korean text defined in any Korean standard called Wansung style (완성형). So, you are to test the "assembled" syllable to the table to see if there is such a syllable). Then you will find "소" in the table. So, you will display "소".

Now the next char, "ㅂ" is written. Then here it becomes a little complicated. Because there is a syllable "솝" in the table, first it will attach ㅂ to the preceding syllable. So, it will display "솝". However, things are not determined yet completely. A user writes the next char, "ㅏ". It's pretty sure that there is no syllable without first/beginning consonant (Ja). It will look up the table, but fail to find a syllable "ㅏ".

So, it will guess the ㅂ (edited from ㅅ. it was typo) attached to the previous syllable actually belongs to the 2nd syllable. And it should display "소바". Now, ㅇ is typed. Then it tries to attach the ㅇ to the second syllable. So it displays 소방. (At this moment it can also lookup 방 in the table. And it is found.)

Now, "ㅊ" is typed. Probably internally it can test 소방ㅊ where o and ㅊ exist under 바 (I can't write it, because there is no such syllable with o and ㅊ exist together under 바, like 밝.). However, there is no such syllable. So, it instantly determines that ㅊ belongs to the next syllable.

Then "ㅏ" is typed. It will assemble ㅊ and ㅏ to make 차. When you press the space key or return key or any other white space key, it will finish composing Hangul.

This is a simple case. In Korean, there are more complicated syllables like 빨, 꼭, 헗, etc. For the first consonants, 복자음 (BokJaUm, Double Consonants) like ㅃ, ㄲ in 빨 and 꼭, people type ㅂ and ㅅ by pressing the shift key. Then it will display ㅃ and ㄲ. So, picking up how may consonants and determine where (previous syllable or next syllable) it belongs to can be easy if a user type with keyboard. (However, there are some nice Korean input methods for Windows and Xterm, where it allows to type ㅂ twice to make ㅃ. It's kind of an intelligent feature. But testing text like 빱빠라빱, 흙을 can be complicated because you end up testing 3 or 4 consonants grouped like {1,3}, {2,2}, {3, 1}.

The bad news is... because you are writing handwriting recognition, you may need to handle such complicated case if you input recognized Hangul characters one by one into a Korean input method engine. However, if you write up your own input method in your app, you can maintain its own state machine, so it can be easier. But as you can see, it's a trade off. Depending on the existing input method engine and ingesting each char into it. (Hmmm... wait... Maybe the input method engine can handle those complicated cases too.)

FYI, I would like to introduce two open source projects. One is a [Korean input method Finder module for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/hanulim/), and the other is [an input method engine](http://code.google.com/p/libhangul/) with which you can make a Korean input method. Also, there is a Korean input method for X-Windows hosted [here](http://code.google.com/p/nabi/). If you prefer Windows project to look up, [here is one](http://kldp.net/projects/saenaru/).

The latter two were hosted at KLDP.net, a Korean open source project hosting site, but they were moved to Google code. As far as I can remember, "SaeNaRu" and "Nabi" (butterfly) can support typing the same consonant twice to make a double consonant.

For more detailed information, you can look up the libhangul and nabi. (I remember that the input method part of code was almost the same between libhangul and nabi before. But at that time they were separated and expected to evolve independently. So, I guess that they are different.

OK. The first thing is done.

Now let's move on to the second issue. (This is the part I said you may know about already. But just to complete my explanation, let me explain this also.)

It's about what character to choose as an input to your probable Korean input method state machine or a engine like libhangul. There are basically two representation of composed (on display) Hangul characters : Composed and Decomposed. Composed one contains fully composed chars. For example, 사랑합니다, each syllable, 사, 랑, 합, 니, 다 is saved as such. They are not stored as ㅅ, ㅏ, ㄹ, ㅏ, ㅇ, ㅎ, ㅏ, ㅂ, ㄴ, ㅣ, ㄷ, ㅏ. 
That is composed representation in Unicode. This representation is usually used by text editors, etc. The other representation is decomposed in Unicode. It's like ㅅ, ㅏ, ㄹ, ㅏ, ㅇ, ㅎ, ㅏ, ㅂ, ㄴ, ㅣ, ㄷ, ㅏ.

This representation is usually used by file systems. For example, if you put a file name in Hangul on Windows, and access the folder which contains it from Mac, it will be displayed like ㅅㅏㄹㅏㅇㅎㅏㅂㄴㅣㄷㅏ although it is displayed as 사랑합니다 on Windows.

However, there is another set of characters if memory serves, which is just a list of Hangul consonants and vowels. Although they may look same or similar to decomposed syllables, they are actually different in that the location where they are drawn is in middle a space where a character is drawn. Its purpose is to present Hangul characters in Korean alphabet tables or things like that for education purpose (or any other purpose.)

So, I'm not sure what characters (i.e. the decomposed or the characters for the list of Hangul consonants and vowels) to ingest to a input method state machine or input method engine you choose or implement. If you implement it, its your choice, but if you use some external libraries for the engine, you need to figure it out.

Also, as I mentioned in my blog post, there are two variants in each composed and decomposed representation, which are all defined in Unicode standard. So, well.. yeah.. I agree. It's quite a bit of work.

As for me, I tried to make an input method for Mac, (when Apple announced they would get rid of the Finder plugin architecture for security issue), but at that time libhangul (Yeah.. I tried to use it) was being changed a lot. So, until it stabilized, I decided to hold off. But because I became very busy at work and tired when I got home, so I didn't make progress on my own input method. So, I believe the state of the libhangul project is much better now than ever. So, it's good try at least to take a look at it.

Also, if you don't have Windows, it would be good to try hanterm or any xterm derivatives which supports Hangul input in itself. The source code will be available at their hosting web site.

Good luck with your project, and if there are more things to ask me, please do so.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive reply! 
libhangul (http://code.google.com/p/libhangul ) which you suggested seems doing the job. 
I am looking at the code right now and will post more info about my experience!

Comment: libhangul (code.google.com/p/libhangul ) does the conversion! See the answer I posted below for the details (I couldn’t post it here because of the 600 character limit).

Answer (score 2):

Check out these system level text-input facility. I never used these, but looks promising.

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4-SW8
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput

---

Because iOS doesn't support system-wide keyboard customization, everybody just use system-default input facility. And handling of Hangul composition is all different by every operating-systems or platforms. (MS/Apple/Samsung/LG or others) So the best way is using system-supplied facility such as UITextField for consistency for users. Or you should accurately simulate how your platform OS does it. Of course you can make it yourself, but users won't like it.

Though I'm not expert on this topic - Korean Hangul compositor -, but I don't think there's simple algorithm without table lookup. Anyway if you really want to implement it yourself, these are all the core problems you have to handle.

- Compositing your visual symbols into consonants and vowels which defined in Unicode.
- Determining initial-consonant / final-consonants by placement of vowels.

It wouldn't be so hard, but anyway ability to modify preceding character sequence is *required*. You cannot implement Korean input with only one-way stream unless you have separate key for initial/final consonants which are looks *same*.

Unicode defines all valid set of Jamo components. Usually those components are too many to be presented on a device. And also inefficient. Most Korean input system decomposes those Jamo again and composite them once before compositing final litter. You also can identify and decompose them visually just like Korean people do.

After you get initial/final-consonants and vowels which are defined in Unicode standard, Unicode Normalization feature (such as `-[NSString precomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping]`) will do the rest of jobs.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive reply! Is there an easy way to determine initial and final consonants? The number of letters in each syllabic block varies from 2 to 5, which makes finding initial and final consonants difficult. To make things even worse, the user may mistakenly start a block with a vowel or write three consonants in a row. In all these cases, the program must use the right unicode for the letters (in this example, I guess the program must use the code for a compatibility Jamo instead of the code for a conjoining Jamo).

Comment: Actually, all consonants with same figure are all same. There's no semantic or phonetic difference between initial or final consonants. It's just separation by its positioning in sequence. So all determination is just heuristic. You know, all consonants before vowels are initial-consonants, and others are final-consonants. Determine them by vowels position first, and override last few of them for unexpected vowel occurrence.

Comment: And you're right for incomplete composition. I see most apps just show broken components if the composition is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

libhangul (code.google.com/p/libhangul ) does the conversion! It has several functions to handle different types of keyboards (i.e., keyboards with different layouts) and converting the keys to the Unicodes of Hanguls.
It also has several functions which combine the Hanguls to make syllables (they basically implement table lookups that Eonil has mentioned in his response).

Libhangul stores the Hanguls in its buffer as it receives them (it does not output them). After receiving enough Hanguls and successfully converting them into a syllable, it outputs the syllable. Unfortunately, this is quite confusing for the user. The way around this is displaying the buffer content on the screen. After receiving a new Hangul, what has been displayed must be erased. If a syllable has been successfully formed, then the syllable is displayed. Otherwise, the buffer content is displayed again. Note that you can’t just display the new Hangul on the screen. You must erase what you have displayed before and read the previous Hanguls and the new one from the buffer and display them on the screen again. 
The reason is that Libhangul may change the code for the previous Hanguls stored in the buffer to make it possible to combine them with the new Hangul.  This way, you will get the updated Hanguls.

Also note if the user changes the location of the cursor, the buffer must be emptied.
Additionally, if the user presses backspace, then, the last Hangul displayed on the screen must be erased and must be removed from the buffer.
Libhangul has also some features for correcting typos. For example, if you typeᅡ and ᄉ, it converts them into사.

Thank you JongAm Park and Eonil for your help and thoughtful comments! Since my reputation is less than 15 at this point, I can’t upvote your answers, but I will do when I can.

Comment: Yes. the problem you described here causes a symptom called 도깨비불(Do-Kkae-Bi-Bool, or Ghost Flame or Fire ). For many years of implementation of Korean input method from early 80's, people successfully got rid of the symptom.

Glad to hear that my explanation was helpful to you. :)