# How do I decompose a unicode character in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, unicode

How can I decompose a unicode character like `밥` into it's components of `ㅂㅏㅂ`?

I want to test to see if the decomposition ends with `ㅂ`, and then if it does, remove that and recompose the character. For example, turn `밥` to `바` or turn `덥` to `더`.

Comment: See what you can dig up from here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/13034977/1042240 user worked on the same scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSString` has a `decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` function that does exactly that.